# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application when importing package in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am currently trying to import some Python package(matplotlib, pandas & numpy) using Jupyter Notebook. However, when I try to do so, this error appears:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
--> 142     from . import core
    143     from .core import *
    144     from . import compat

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py in <module>
     21             # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     22             # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 23             WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     24             DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     25     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    354 
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:
    358             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I have already tried to install these packages using Anaconda prompt via `conda install numpy`, `conda install pandas`. I did not encounter such issues importing the package in IDLE using cmd. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I had done uninstall/reinstalls of Anaconda and numpy/pandas, uninstalled 32-bit versions, and various other suggestions that people made, but none of that worked. However, notice that the error is referencing `~\AppData\Roaming\Python\...`.

I was able to solve the problem by deleting `~\AppData\Roaming\Python`.